# How to implement the 4 Bell states on the IBM Q (composer)?

Tags: quantum-gate, entanglement, ibm-q-experience

I would like to simulate the 4 ["Bell States"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state) on the [IBM composer](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/editor)?

How can I best implement those 4 Bell states using the existing set of gates ?

Here below you see the definition of the 4 Bell states.

[image: The 4 bell states]

The first bell state can be easily implemented on the composer through a Hadamard gate and a CNOT gate as follows:

[image: first Bell state]

but how can I implement the other 3 bell states ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember that the [Hadamard (**H**) gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Hadamard_(H)_gate) maps $|0\rangle$ to $\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $|1\rangle$ to $\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$, while the [CNOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate) has the following conversion table:

[image]

So, you can use the same circuit:

[image]

but begin in the states $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ to get the other three Bell states (you can easily convert to these states from $|00\rangle$ using the [Pauli-X gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Pauli-X_gate_(=_NOT_gate))).

[image]

Source: [Todd Brun's lecture notes, Part-11](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~tbrun/Course/lecture11.pdf)

Answer (score 11):

One of the possible solutions:

$|\Phi^+\rangle = \textrm{CNOT} \cdot  H_1  |00 \rangle$
$|\Phi^-\rangle = Z_1 |\Phi^+\rangle = Z_1 \cdot \textrm{CNOT} \cdot  H_1  |00 \rangle$
$|\Psi^+\rangle = X_2 |\Phi^+\rangle = X_2 \cdot \textrm{CNOT} \cdot  H_1  |00 \rangle$
$|\Psi^-\rangle = Z_1 |\Psi^+\rangle = Z_1 \cdot X_2 \cdot \textrm{CNOT} \cdot  H_1  |00 \rangle$

Where $Z_i$ and $X_i$ act on the $i^\textrm{th}$ qubit.

---

**So here is $|\Phi^-\rangle$:**

[image]

**Here is $|\Psi^+\rangle$:**

[image]

**And here is $|\Psi^-\rangle$:**

[image]

---

Another solution is:

$|\Phi^+\rangle = \textrm{CNOT} \cdot  H_1  |00 \rangle$
$|\Phi^-\rangle = X_1 \cdot \textrm{CNOT} \cdot  H_1  |00 \rangle$
$|\Psi^+\rangle = X_2 \cdot \textrm{CNOT} \cdot  H_1  |00 \rangle$
$|\Psi^-\rangle = Z_1 X_2\cdot \textrm{CNOT} \cdot  H_1  |00 \rangle$

Comment: Are you assuming that we can only begin in the state $|00\rangle$? Is that a *necessity* for the IBM Q composer? Asking because I don't have experience with the IBM Q composer.

Comment: @Blue, yes IBM Q composer seems always to begin in state $|00\rangle$ but it can be easily converted to e.g. state $|01\rangle$ by using an $X$ gate.

Comment: I've included the solution that starts with states different from $|00\rangle$, but do I have to put the diagrams in there too or is what I have good enough for you?